# Run GDB with Linux

Tags: python, linux, linux-kernel, gdb

I'm trying to run gdb with linux kernel. I built linux with CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y, and tried to run python script "vmlinux-gdb.py" in gdb, which is in "../linux/scripts/gdb". But as result I got error

```
File "../linux/scripts/gdb/linux/proc.py", line 15, in <module>
    from linux import constants
ImportError: cannot import name constants
```

There are several files in directory "../linux/scripts/gdb/linux":

```
clk.py           device.py     lists.py     proc.pyc     tasks.pyc
config.py        dmesg.py      lists.pyc    rbtree.py    timerlist.py
config.pyc       dmesg.pyc     Makefile     rbtree.pyc   utils.py
constants.py.in  genpd.py      modules.py   symbols.py   utils.pyc
cpus.py          __init__.py   modules.pyc  symbols.pyc
cpus.pyc         __init__.pyc  proc.py      tasks.py
```

So, this directory hasn't file constants.py.
And my question is how to build constants.py from constants.py.in?

Comment: _constants.py. **in**_ means that a buildsystem (usually via `make`) has to take the pattern and generate a real python module. I think you forgot to build it.

Comment: @0andriy, yes, i understand that it should be build by makefile. But i don't know which ones should be used if i've already build linux

Comment: I don't see a top-level *Makefile* which has a `gdb` target (you may grep yourself and find it if any), but at least `make scripts/gdb` should work as per https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/gdb/linux/Makefile.